# Deploying .lib file in the Salesforce org

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce

I am using this code: https://github.com/pradeepramakrishna/Lightning-Experience/tree/master/aura-components to compile on my org.

I have got one components as *eventLib.lib* and *interactive.js* in **eventLib** folder. I have put this folder in **c:MyDevOrg\force-app\main\default\aura** folder in the local machine and tried to deploy in the org using VSCode but it didn't work.

I tried creating folder in the **Files** tab and added the *interactive.js* in the folder but that is also not seeming to work with the Aura components.

How can I deploy this lib into the org as it is being used in some Aura components.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know what you're trying to achieve. You asked a very technical question to which the answer is "you're probably doing it wrong". Instead try to write what business functionality you are trying to achieve and you might get better answers.

You shouldn't have to import `ui:eventLib`. It's supposed to be part of core Salesforce's Aura components framework. But.

1. You've referenced a repo that wasn't updated in a while, no promises this still compiles / is best way to do X.
2. This repo seems to rely on open source Aura framework which is well... [dead in the water](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura).
3. You might be able to reuse something from this repo in your app using SF's built-in tags - but whole `ui:` library has been [deprecated. Announced](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_aura_ui_deprecate.htm&type=5&release=232) in Winter'20 = almost 2 years ago, finally dead in May 2021.
4. I don't think `eventLib` was ever exposed, might be something needed just in open source version which complicates the matter more. The answer would be to not work with the really "decompiled" tags but with their higher abstracted versions like `ui:inputDate`.

So, back to my question. What exactly are you trying to achieve.

- You want to build something on pure SF platform (use pure Aura/LWC).
- Want to have an app written in Angular, React etc, pure JS, connecting to SF data via API? (build it, upload as static resourcethen import using [lightning:container](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:container/documentation))
- want to prettify an existing Java/PHP/.NET app, make it look more Lightning-ish and embed it as iframe? (look into https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/ and connected apps + "canvas")
- want to expose piece of SF as reusable element that can be embedded in another website but could even be an Outlook plugin? (search for "lightning out")
- want to look at modern equivalent of that old open source Aura repo and decide what to do next? Check https://lwc.dev/ out.